# Specifying a package identity name with Desktop App Converter

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-store, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I am using DesktopAppConverter.exe to create an appx for Windows Store.

I get the following errors on upload to MS:

```
Invalid package identity name: XXXX (expected: 184YYY.XXX)
Invalid package family name: XXX_eqm6jq3xyprpt (expected: 184YYY.XXX_eqm6jq3xyprpt)
```

How can I specify a package identity name anf family name, I am currently using the command:

```
DesktopAppConverter.exe 
-Installer C:\input\XXX.exe 
-InstallerArguments /VERYSILENT 
-Destination C:\output 
-PackageName "XXX" 
-PackagePublisherDisplayName "YYY" 
-Publisher CN="00000000-E45F-4F04-9805-00000000000" 
-Version 3.0.0.0 
-sign 
-MakeAppx 
-Verbose
```

I tried all the parameters from here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter

However none of them is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the command line is supposed to be :

```
DesktopAppConverter.exe 
-Installer C:\input\XXX.exe 
-InstallerArguments /VERYSILENT 
-Destination C:\output 
-PackageName "XXX" 
-Publisher CN="00000000-E45F-4F04-9805-00000000000" 
-Version 3.0.0.0 
-sign 
-MakeAppx 
-Verbose
```

You just need to set the Identity Parameters to match the App identity info (package identity name and publisher) in Dashboard. Other optional parameters will be set to the value passed for them.

You could try modifying your converted package by changing the `package identity name` in appxManifest file to match the info in Dev Center. And to publish your app package to the Store, you need to fill out [this form](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge) and Microsoft will contact you to start the onboarding process.

Comment: PackageName can not contain a . so I think thats bits wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no command will work.

After spending months dealing with Microsofts very slow to respond developer support the issue was discovered.

The desktop app converter does not support the app manifest value format required, it gives errors stating that the format of the values is outside the specification of the format allowed.

The solution from Microsoft is to export using any value, then edit and app manifest xml file to the correct values, then use the app x packager to re package app.

My guess is that the desktop app converter has not updated to reflect current app store manifest requirements.