# Desktop App Converter how to pass a period in -PackageName

Tags: desktop-application

I have the same problem as the person in this question

[Specifying a package identity name with Desktop App Converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42580695/specifying-a-package-identity-name-with-desktop-app-converter)

except I can not work out how in the form -PackageName string, It will not work with a period in the string or a number in the front of the string which is my problem, as my package identity contains both?

Answer (score 0):

A period will work in the -PackageName argument. PackageName is used as a fallback for several command line arguments (when not specified). Try something like the following (with your other arguments):

```
-PackageName "12103MyTech.CoolestAppEver" -PackageDisplayName "CoolestAppEver" -AppDisplayName "CoolestAppEver" -AppId "CoolestAppEver"
```

This will create an appx with the name '12103MyTech.CoolestAppEver.appx', all of the values in AppxManifest.xml will be properly specified.

Comment: Thanks Mike that was the answer.